# gnu screen: reattach all previously detached sessions

Tags: gnu-screen, unix

I have a few windows in a single `screen` session and then I want to detach my session. There is no problem with that.

But I can't find a way to restore all windows within my previously detached session. I can see that I can restore just one of them by ID.

But how can I reattach exact the same session environment with all the windows in it?

--

`Updated:`

If I type screen -d -r, this is what is says:

```
There are several suitable screens on:
    21074.pts-7.atx (05/29/2010 02:26:32 PM)    (Attached)
    3420.pts-3.atx  (05/29/2010 12:16:41 AM)    (Detached)
Type "screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host" to resume one of them.
```

How can I reattach all of them?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`screen -d -r : Reattach a session and if necessary detach it first.`

This will reattach your old session, will all its windows. If your session is still attached, it will detach it before attaching it to the current terminal. This is quite useful when for example you have kept your screen session in an ssh terminal on another computer.

Comment: tonio, please check out question's update. Where is my mistake here?

Comment: In your update, screen says it can't reattach a session, because it does not know which one to reattach: there are two. IT even gives you a hist on how to select one or another session (when you do not give a session id, it expects there is only one, and uses that one).

Here the firs one is already attached, while the second is detached. Try reattaching it to the current terminal with
`screen -r 3420.pts-3.atx`

Comment: I got it now. Thank you, tonio!

Answer (score 1):

To reattach **all** previously detached sessions I use this little script.

```
#!/bin/sh
for line in `screen -ls | grep Detached |  awk '{print $1}'`; do
   xdotool key control+shift+t type "screen -r $line"
   xdotool key KP_Enter
done
```

**"control+shift+t"** happened to be a shortcut in my terminal for opening a new tab and it may be different shortcut in yours.